Updating a Java Map by different methods
I have a Java Map:
Map<String,String> mapThings = new HashMap<>();
updateMapThings(mapThings, sourceMap); // sourceMap is the original Map which has all the 
                                       // values I want to populate mapThings with.

So now mapTings is like below
{
    "a" : "A",
    "b" : "B",
    "c" : "C"
}

With a,A,b,B,c,C (all the key/values) populated from sourceMap
Now I want to populate mapThings with more key/values from sourceMap2, so mapThings will become
{
    "a" : "A",
    "b" : "B",
    "c" : "C",
    "d" : "D",
    "e" : "E",
    "f" : "F"
}

where d,D,e,E,f,F are all key/values populated from sourceMap2.
Should I call
updateMapThings(mapThings, sourceMap2);

This is where I get confused whether Java is Pass By Value or Reference. How do I cleanly update the same map with different key/values from more than one source?

I don't understand what this has to do with pass-by-value or pass-by-reference. Whether this works or not depends on how you've written updateMapThings. If it just calls Map.putAll then it will work.

Java is pass by value.  The "value" is a reference to a heap object (the map).  So Java objects have reference semantics even though Java is strictly pass by value.  Thus there's no problem with the code you show and it's completely normal.

What is "updateMapThings"? A method that you have written? It is unclear where your confusion comes from. If you have declared your map as Map<String,String> mapThings = new HashMap<>(); then there are several ways to add key value pairs. The most likely is probably mapThings.putAll(sourceMap2); but also look at the methods that start with Map.compute... and Map.merge

This question is similar to: Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Java is pass-by-value, in the sense that if your method tries to assign a new value to an argument passed to it (e.g., mapThings = somethingElse), it won't affect the variable after the method's end.
However, when passing an object (such as a map) to a method, you're passing a reference. This means that if you invoke any methods that alter it, it will remain altered when the method completes.
In short - you can call updateMapThings(mapThings, sourceMap) followed by updateMapThings(mapThings, sourceMap2)

Everything is passed by value, the difference is in what we're passing, whether a primitive type (int, double, char, and so on) or a reference type (an Object).
In the first case (primitive types), the value stored in the memory address of a primitive variable represents an "actual value", like 5 in the case of an int, and it is copied into the corresponding method's parameter.
In the second case (reference types), the value stored in the memory address of your reference variable is another memory address. Specifically, the memory address of the object pointed by the reference. Therefore, when you're "passing an object to a method", you're actually copying the memory address contained in your reference variable into the method's parameter. This type of passage is commonly called passing by reference, while in the case of primitive types, it is referred to as passing by value. However, in both cases we're passing the value (the content) of a variable. The distinction is made on what this content represents: a value for the data type or a memory address.
In your case, when you're passing the variable mapThings to the method updateMapThings, you're copying the address contained by mapThings into the first parameter of the method. Like so, both references (the one passed to the method and the method's parameter) are pointing to the same object in the heap memory. Therefore, if you want to update mapThings with the content of two different maps, you can simply invoke the same method a second time with the second source map.
updateMapThings(mapThings, sourceMap);
updateMapThings(mapThings, sourceMap2);

